# Function to dampen a value

Tags: function, math, date, relevance

I have a list of documents each having a relevance score for a search query. I need older documents to have their relevance score dampened, to try to introduce their date in the ranking process. I already tried fiddling with functions such as 1/(1+date_difference), but the reciprocal function is too discriminating for close recent dates.

I was thinking maybe a mathematical function with range (0..1) and domain(0..x) to amplify their score, where the x-axis is the age of a document. It's best to explain what I further need from the function by an image:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the picture you linked to? Do you want the function to be constant after some `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decaying behavior is often modeled well by an exponentional function (many decaying processes in nature also follow it). You would use 2 positive parameters `A` and `B` and get

```
y(x) = A exp(-B x)
```

Since you want a `y`-range [0,1] set `A=1`. Larger `B` give slower decays.

Comment: Thanks. Found this result to perform best. Used it as follows:
    exp(-0.1*$days);

Answer (score 1):

If a simple 1/(1+x) decreases too quickly too soon, a [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) like 1/(1+e^-x) or the error function might be better suited to your purpose. Let the current date be somewhere in the negative numbers for such a function, and you can get a value that is current for some configurable time and then decreases towards a base value.

Answer (score 1):

```
log((x+1)-age_of_document)
```

Where the base of the logarithm is (x+1). Note the x is as per your diagram and is the "threshold". If the age of the document is greater than x the score goes negative. Multiply by the maximum possible score to introduce scaling.

E.g. Domain = (0,10) with a maximum score of 10: [10*(log(11-x))/log(11)](http://fooplot.com/plot/og3f9iczcx)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but as thiton says, you might want to use a sigmoid function instead, since it has a "floor" value for your long tail data points. E.g.:

[0.8/(1+5^(x-3)) + 0.2](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIwLjgvKDErNV4oeC0zKSkrMC4yIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMTdENjFFIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTYuNSIsIjIwIiwiLTQiLCI0Il19XQ--) - You can adjust the constants 5 and 3 to control the slope of the curve. The 0.2 is where the floor will be.